# Is the l-adic Euler number a derived invariant?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is the $\ell$-adic Euler number a derived invariant?

Explicitly,  if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective varieties which are derived-equivalent, must their $\ell$-adic Euler numbers be equal?

Comment: Here is a sketch. I'm not completely convinced all these holes can be filled in. You have enough conditions so that Orlov's result tells you the derived equivalence is given by a FM transform. There is an etale chern character so you can get an induced map on etale cohomology. Use the fact that it was an equivalence to prove that this is a vector space isomorphism. It may not preserve degree, but it does preserve even and odd parts. Thus you may mess up individual $\ell$-adic Betti numbers, but the alternating sum should be the same.

Comment: See par. 5.2 in Daniel Huybrechts, "Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry" (Oxford Mathematical Monographs, The
Clarendon Press Oxford University Press, Oxford, 2006) for the char. 0 case (where the l-adic Betti Euler number coincides with the singular one). 